# Посоветуйте реализацию звездного рейтинга на svg

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

Необходимо сделать звездный рейтинг, и главным условием является то что он должен быть в svg что бы хорошо отображался на ретина дисплеях. Сколько гуглил, не нашел решений с использованием svg иконок, но больше всего понравился [вариант на fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/examples/#custom) планирую только создать отдельный шрифт со своими нужными иконками, и в связи с этим хотел поинтересоваться, может кто знает решение получше?

Comment: А в чём проблема взять абсолютно любой звёздный рейтинг и просто поменять в нём картинки на svg?

Comment: В тех рейтингах что я видел изображения звезд задаются background-ом, а какой смысл от svg изображения когда оно задано через background?

Comment: Такой же, как и от любого другого svg. Непонятно в чём вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот реализация на `svg` точно такой же картинки как вы хотите.

```js
$('.star.rating').click(function(){  
  $(this).parent().attr('data-stars',$(this).data('rating'));
});
```

```css
.stars {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.stars:hover .star polygon {
  fill: #ffd055 !important;
}
.stars .star {
  float: left;
}
.stars .star polygon {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}
.stars .star:hover ~ .star polygon {
  fill: #d8d8d8 !important;
}
.stars[data-stars] .star polygon {
  fill: #ffd055;
}
.stars[data-stars="1"] .star:nth-child(1) ~ .star polygon {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}
.stars[data-stars="2"] .star:nth-child(2) ~ .star polygon {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}
.stars[data-stars="3"] .star:nth-child(3) ~ .star polygon {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}
.stars[data-stars="4"] .star:nth-child(4) ~ .star polygon {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}
.stars[data-stars="5"] .star:nth-child(5) ~ .star polygon {
  fill: #d8d8d8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stars" data-stars="1">
 <svg height="25" width="23" class="star rating" data-rating="1">
    <polygon points="9.9, 1.1, 3.3, 21.78, 19.8, 8.58, 0, 8.58, 16.5, 21.78" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
  </svg>
  <svg height="25" width="23" class="star rating" data-rating="2">
    <polygon points="9.9, 1.1, 3.3, 21.78, 19.8, 8.58, 0, 8.58, 16.5, 21.78" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
  </svg>
  <svg height="25" width="23" class="star rating" data-rating="3">
    <polygon points="9.9, 1.1, 3.3, 21.78, 19.8, 8.58, 0, 8.58, 16.5, 21.78" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
  </svg>
  <svg height="25" width="23" class="star rating" data-rating="4">
    <polygon points="9.9, 1.1, 3.3, 21.78, 19.8, 8.58, 0, 8.58, 16.5, 21.78" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
  </svg>
  <svg height="25" width="23" class="star rating" data-rating="5">
    <polygon points="9.9, 1.1, 3.3, 21.78, 19.8, 8.58, 0, 8.58, 16.5, 21.78" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```